# Get top most parent by nth child id?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, greatest-n-per-group, hierarchical-data

Now there is a question we commonly use this technique to maintain the parent child relation i.e we store all the entities in one tables with a **parent_id** column and all top most parents have **0** in the parent_id column this is a good and normalized technique i agree but there is a disadvantage also ,  it’s slow and inefficient. This is mainly caused by the recursion like for each parent we have to run the query again and again to make a tree

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE parent_id=something
```

I have looked at the solutions some might try to do it with any programming language by running query again and again which makes a loads on server , Some have provided the stored procedure but that also involves the recursion.

So my question is can we do it with one database query for the tree(joins or subqueries)?

- if we know the depth or if we don't know  the depth ?
- if it is possible so how can we get the top most parent(i.e parent_id=0) of any child?
- if it is not possible then why this technique is so famous, while it has the flaws or we have another solution for this?

  I have added the sql fiddle but it only has the schema

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f1e23)

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL doesn't support recursive functions so is not well suited to this "adjacency list" model of storing hierarchical data.  You should consider remodelling your schema to embed the hierarchical structure in a form MySQL can exploit, such as "nested sets" or "transitive closures".

Comment: @eggyal but now a days many cms do follow this technique like most commonly used wordpress also provides the nth menu level, page level and category level so my question is there a better way to store and get the tree without running multiple queries ?

Comment: You can self-join for every generation you wish to fetch, but the depth will always be limited by the number of joins in the query.

Comment: @dianuj: then you might think about migrating to a more feature-rich DBMS which lets you easily work with such a model.

Comment: Why are you storing 0 (instead of NULL) in the `parent_id`? Do you have one "master root" that is always 0? Do you have a proper FOREIGN KEY on `parent_id` (I don't see it in SQL Fiddle)? EDIT: Belay that - you are using MyISAM which does not enforce FKs. Your data _will_ get corrupted eventually. You should really consider using a more complete engine like InnoDB, or even a different DBMS.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic the fiddle was just an example not a perfect scehma therefore in my question i have asked for **we have another solution for this?**

Comment: Investigate punctuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with MYSQL, I have been working mainly with SQL Server in my career. In SQL Server, it's possible to do it with only 1 query by using the `WITH` statement.

This demonstrates how to get all children of an object (id=3) at all levels

```
With pa as (
     select pa1.*
     From prarent as pa1
     Where id = 3
     union all
     select pa2.*
     from pa join prarent as pa2 on pa.id = pa2.parent_id
  )
select * from pa where pa.id != 3
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5885/4)

Another example to get all parents of an object (id=7) up to the top most

```
With pa as (
     select pa1.*
     From prarent as pa1
     Where id = 7
     union all
     select pa2.*
     from pa join prarent as pa2 on pa.parent_id = pa2.id
  )
select * from pa where pa.id != 7
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5885/5)

Another example to get only the topmost parent

```
With pa as (
     select pa1.*
     From prarent as pa1
     Where id = 7
     union all
     select pa2.*
     from pa join prarent as pa2 on pa.parent_id = pa2.id
  )
select top 1 * 
from pa 
where pa.id != 7
order by id asc
```

In this example, I assume that the id is incrementally and i use a simple way (just for demonstration purposes) to get the topmost using `order by`. You may use another technique depending on your database design.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5885/6)

Using this similar technique, you can do more, like getting the bottommost child,....

Comment: Thank you v much if you ever know this kind functionality is possible in mysql then please edit this answer , and here is your reward :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of levels, or a lot of data, this will be impractical.

Otherwise, you can try to emulate what the recursive functions do. Even if you won't get the same performance, this won't matter if you do not have much data, nor too many levels.

The general procedure would be as follows:

1. For a given parent, select the record with that ID
2. Also, select records with that as the PARENT_ID, and UNION this with the previous
3. The sub-query in step #2 gives the first-level children, so you can write a query that selects their IDs, and use this as a sub-select in a third query that say "where PARENT_ID IN (sub-select)"
4. This will be analogous to step #3, and go on this way

It will look something like this: ([see the Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f1e23/17/0))

```
select *
from prarent P0
where id = 3

union 

select *
from prarent P1
where parent_id = 3

union 

select *
from prarent P2
where parent_id in
 (  select distinct id
    from prarent P1
    where p1.parent_id = 3
 )

union 

select *
from prarent P3
where parent_id in
 (  select distinct id
    from prarent P2
    where parent_id in
    (  select distinct id
       from prarent P1
       where p1.parent_id = 3
    )
 )
```

Comment: if you see you have depth-1 unions in the query with sub selects and you have already mentioned in your answer **If you have a lot of levels, or a lot of data, this will be impractical** i want a generic solution if not then why this method is so popular ?

Comment: If the logicial struture is a tree, then there are few alternatives that are still flexible. Practically speaking, when I've used a "BOM" structure, the use-cases have been such that one focuses on a certain number of levels, and drills down if required. So, practically speaking, I'd probably keep this structure, even if the database did not offer SQL with easy recursion. If you have the ability to mix SQL with some 3-G code (even if it in a stored-procedure), performance is unlikley to be a significant problem in most cases. A hassle to code, but not a performance issue.